# PHP $_FILES file details

Tags: php, file-upload

It might be a strange question but I am asked if it is possible and I don't know the answer.
In Windows it is possible to add details to a file, like an author and labels etc. 
Is there any way in PHP I can read these details when this file is uploaded to the server (our client would like to use it to tag files on their server).

Comment: No, none of this information is passed in the HTTP protocol when uploading files. Read the documentation of `$_FILES`, it tells you everything you can tell about the file.

Comment: ...however, there's nothing stopping you from having other fields with this information accessible through `$_POST`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931378/how-to-read-file-properties-with-php

Answer (score 1):

That information you mention it's called metadata.

You can use this php library to do the trick.

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box functionality doesn't pass this information when uploading files using PHP.

[The documentation for $_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) shows all of the details you can get about the file